# Custom Code in Typewriter Generated Classes

Tags: typescript, typewriter

I am using [Typewriter](http://frhagn.github.io/Typewriter/) to generate TypeScript models based on EF Core Entities, however on the models we have added custom properties and methods, which are overwritten by Typewriter whenever the entity changes, is there any way to specify that Typewriter should keep code within a section of the ts model when regenerating the model?

breeze.js have made a [TypeScriptEntityGen](https://github.com/Breeze/breeze.tooling/tree/master/TypeScriptEntityGen) which workes that way, but is a hazzle to implement compared to Typewriter, so I would prefer to stick with Typewriter.

```
export class InternationalOrder extends DomainModel.NorthwindIB.Order {
    /// <code> Place custom code between code tags

    /// </code>

    // Generated code. Do not place code below this line.
    customsDescription: string;
    exciseTax: number;           
}
```

Comment: Have you considered keeping the extra code in a separate file and using augmentation to add methods to the classes ? Would keep things cleaner, generated code in one place, hand crafted code in another.

Comment: thats not a dumb idea, I knew about type merging in TypeScript but read it wasnt supported cross files, but augmentation solves that problem, thanks for the tip! :)

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir why not just extend them then?

Comment: Because then you would need to use the extended versions everywhere. I'm guessing your generated classes reference other generated classes, it would be more difficult to get them to reference the extrended versions of the class\

Comment: Good Point @TitianCernicova-Dragomir